# del in cassandra cli not work sometimes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

Sometimes `del` command in cassandra doesn't work.

```
  [default@ran] get private[7d024b55fbe7e3a0064b3613c635dd8]; 
    => (name=1, value=1414818289748, timestamp=1414818321277000)
    => (name=2, value=1414809690283, timestamp=1414816876801000)
    => (name=3, value=1414809773084, timestamp=1414816882177000)
    => (name=4, value=1414809715931, timestamp=1414816886825000)
    => (name=5, value=1414809793752, timestamp=1414816891209000)
    => (name=20141101050451971, value=1414817296432, timestamp=1414818321277001)
    Returned 6 results.
    Elapsed time: 13 msec(s).
    [default@rankq] del private[7d024b55fbe7e3a0064b3613c635dd8][20141101050451971]; 
    cell removed.
    Elapsed time: 2.44 msec(s).
    [default@ran] get private[7d024b55fbe7e3a0064b3613c635dd8]; 
    => (name=1, value=1414818289748, timestamp=1414818321277000)
    => (name=2, value=1414809690283, timestamp=1414816876801000)
    => (name=3, value=1414809773084, timestamp=1414816882177000)
    => (name=4, value=1414809715931, timestamp=1414816886825000)
    => (name=5, value=1414809793752, timestamp=1414816891209000)
    => (name=20141101050451971, value=1414817296432, timestamp=1414818321277001)
    Returned 6 results.
    Elapsed time: 12 msec(s).
```

I just tried multiple times to delete this but not works and suddenly after multiple it works.
It is a bug of cassandra cli?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a consistency problem. The default consistency level for all r/w operations in cli is `ONE` so if you are working on a multiple nodes instance it's possible that you are getting old data. Try to execute this in cassandra-cli:

```
consistencylevel AS Quorum;
```

And after that repeat a delete/read operation.

HTH,
Carlo